# Jquery iterate through class, count sting length, if shorter than X do something

Tags: jquery, each

I have a site with x instances of a class (they are loaded dynamically through php). In each instance of the class there is a different amount of characters and i want all instances of the class with less than 110 characters to be narrower than the rest.

I have made it this far, which work with one instance of the class , but when two classes are loaded it calculates the total length of all instances of the class. I have looked into .each() for Jquery, but i cant seem to get the syntax right.

JQuery

```
if ($(".quotecontent").text().length < 110) {
        $(".quote").css("width", 500);
        //alert($(".quotecontent").text().length);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="quote">
<div class="quotestart"></div>
<div class="quotecontent"><p>We have a new toy!</p>
<div class="author">- Fernando Alonso</div></div>
<div class="quoteend"></div>
</div>

<div class="quote">
<div class="quotestart"></div>
<div class="quotecontent"><p>Fight to fly, fly to fight, fight to win.</p>
<div class="author">- Motto of the U.S. Navy Fighter Weapons School, TOPGUN</div></div>
<div class="quoteend"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/B3Uwj/11/

Please let me know if I missed anything.

Hope this helps.

**code**

```
$(".quotecontent").each(function() {

    if ($(this).text().length < 110) {
        $(this).parent(".quote").css("width", 500);
        //alert($(".quotecontent").text().length);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and in less than 2 mins. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".quotecontent").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().length < 110;
}).parent('.quote').css("width", 500);
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kh8Hh/)

Comment: +1 for chaining! Although you may want to use `parent(".quote")` instead in case you introduce more layers between `.quotecontent` and `.quote`.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - Thanx, it's a one-liner, just wrote it in three for readability :) -- Actually considered doing that, but in regards to the example code, it's not really necessary, I'll add here, but can't be bothered to update the fiddle ;-)

Comment: @MattiasBuelens If you're introducing more than one layer between `.quotecontent` and `.quote` then `.parent()` isn't the correct function to use. The `.parent()` function only ever traverses up one level in the DOM, it doesn't traverse up until it finds an element that matches. For that, you want `.parents()` or `.closest()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - you're right, but for the code supplied in the question, parent() is probably the best choice, if more layers are added the OP will have to change it to closest().

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Correct, I was mixing up the methods. `$.closest()` seems most appropriate.